# Video call and chat using WebRTC and Pubnub in native iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub, webrtc-ios, xirsys

I'm working on a doctor-patient appointment app on native iOS Swift project. Here I want to implement a live video call with chat using WebRTC and PubNub signaling server. I'm totally new to it. I don't know how to implement this. I have seen some of the Objective-C codes but still I didn't understand. Please help if any of you implement the same in swift.

Comment: AFAIK, we don't have any iOS specific examples at PubNub but you may want to consider Vonage if this is a production app: https://www.pubnub.com/integrations/vonage-video-api-video-chat/

Comment: See Vonage answer below

Answer (score 2):

Highly recommend you reach out to a service such as Vonage (https://www.vonage.com) who can provide HIPAA compliant WebRTC video service for you.

Once you have a set of keys on Vonage, you can use PubNub to move the video session details around the channel in question.
Traditionally I use a JSON object model that looks like this:

```
channel: "UUID of medical session"
messageID: "MessageID on your platform"
messageType: "videoInvite"
sender: "Hilaj"
sessionDetails: "session JWT and/or session token"
timestamp: "1597347054"
```

This means you can send text based messages as well as video invites in the same channel and write the event to logs.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this in Swift (and previously in Objective C) but it is completely proprietary.

You are going to have to download the [Google WebRTC framework](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/refs/heads/master/docs/native-code/development/index.md).

Taking a quick look at PubNub, it looks like it just does signalling. You are still going to need an actual WebRTC server (eg, [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com)). There are others and I'm not really sure which ones support PubNub.